# How to post a list to Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I followed [this example](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/), which allows to post a unique `Person` object. I want a REST service where I can post a collection of `Person` at once, e.g. a list/any collection named `Team` with numerous `Person` objects in just one call.

I mean, my question is not exactly about the `OneToMany` relationship, where you send each person in a REST request. This topic is [well answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-association-in-spring-data-rest).

I want to send a collection of `Person` objects taking advantage of `@RepositoryRestResource` or another feature from Spring Data Rest. Is this possible with Spring Data Rest or should I workaround by creating a controller, receive the list and parse the `Team` list to insert each `Person`?

I found [this feature request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-334), which seems to answer that nowadays Spring Rest Data is missing what I am looking for, but I am not sure.

In my business requirement, application A will post a list of orders to application B and I have to save it in database for future processing, so, after reading about Spring Data Rest and making some samples, I found  its clean architecture amazing and very suitable for my requirement except for the fact that I didn't figure out how to post a list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, AFAIK you can't do that with spring data rest, just read the docs and you will see, that there is no mention about posting a list to collection resource.

The reason for this is unclear to me, but for one thing - the REST itself doesn't really specify how you should do batch operations.
So it's unclear how one should approach that feature, like should you POST a list to collection resource? Or should you export resource like `/someentity/batch` that would be able to patch, remove and add entities in one batch? If you will add list how should you return ids? For single POST to collection spring-data-rest return id in Location header. For batch add this cannot be done.

That doesn't justify that spring-data-rest is missing batch operations. They should implement this IMHO, but at least it can help to understand why are they missing it maybe.

What I can say though is that you can always add your own Controller to the project that would handle /someentity/batch properly and you can even probably make a library out of that, so that you can use it in another projects. Or even fork spring-data-rest and add this feature. Although I tried to understand how it works and failed so far.
But you probably know all that, right?

[There is a feature request for this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-334).

Comment: I will consider your answer as final answer: "Spring Data Rest can't be used to receive a list". Obviously, I respect it but for me Spring Data Rest would be much more useful if it receives a list and insert in database. Of course, I can do it without Spring Data Rest. Just by creating a controler with @RequestBody List<myPojo> and then add all pojos in database. Nevertheless, I would use often Spring Data Rest if I could post a list to my service.

Comment: @JimC Yeah, me too. There is a issue for batch ops in their JIRA I think. I tried to create another issue - SDR doesn't support OrderColumn annotation - but I haven't received any answer.

Answer (score 5):

Based on **user1685095** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947312/1283715), You can make custom Controller `PersonRestController` and expose post `collection of Person` as it seem not exposed yet by `Spring-date-rest`

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/persons")
public class PersonRestController {
private final PersonRepository repo;
@Autowired
public AppointmentRestController(PersonRepository repo) {
    this.repo = repo;
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/batch", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> savePersonList(@RequestBody Resource<PersonWrapper<Person>> personWrapper,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {
    Resources<Person> resources = new Resources<Person>(repo.save(personWrapper.getContent()));
    //TODO add extra links `assembler`
    return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
}
```

}

> **PersonWrapper** to fix:
>
> Can not deserialize instance of org.springframework.hateoas.Resources out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@3298b722; line: 1, column: 1]

**Update**

```
public class PersonWrapper{
 private List<Person> content;
   
public List<Person> getContent(){
return content;
}

public void setContent(List<Person> content){
this.content = content;
}
}

public class Person{
private String name;
private String email;
// Other fields

// GETTER & SETTER 
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what's the Wrapper class? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use `@RequestBody List<Resource<MyPojo>>`.
When the request body does not contain any links, it works well, but
if the element carries a link, the server could not deserialize the request body.

Then I tried to use `@RequestBody Resources<MyPojo>`, but I could not figure out the default name of a list.

Finally, I tried a wrapper which contained `List<Resource<MyPojo>>`, and it works.

Here is my solution:

First create a wrapper class for `List<Resource<MyPojo>>`:

```
public class Bulk<T> {
    private List<Resource<T>> bulk;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Then use `@RequestBody Resource<Bulk<MyPojo>>` for parameters.

Finally, example json with links for create bulk data in one request:

```
{
    "bulk": [
        {
            "title": "Spring in Action",
            "author": "http://localhost:8080/authors/1"
        },
        {
            "title": "Spring Quick Start",
            "author": "http://localhost:8080/authors/2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, helped me a lot. For future reference :
- regarding the `Resources<MyPojo>`, I tried "content" (as it is the name of the list inside the class code) and "entities" but none of that worked : the deserialized content list is always empty (and I don't have the time to dive into it atm)
- regarding the `List<Resource<MyPojo>>`, the exception you'll get is something like : JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `MyPojo` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('/my-link')

Comment: Resource is now EntityModel, 
see here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#migrate-to-1.0.changes.representation-models

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/batchInsert", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> batchInsert(@RequestBody Resources<Person> people, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) throws Exception {
    Iterable<Person> s = repo.save( people.getContent() ); // save entities

    List<PersistentEntityResource> list = new ArrayList<PersistentEntityResource>();
    Iterator<Sample> itr = s.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        list.add( assembler.toFullResource( itr.next() ) );
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok( new Resources<PersistentEntityResource>(list) );
}
```

Comment: Answers containing nothing but code with no description are far from helpful

Answer (score 0):

Base the answer of totran, this is my code:

There are dependencies:

```
springBootVersion = '2.4.2'
springDependencyManagement = '1.0.10.RELEASE'

implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

The codes:

```java
import icu.kyakya.rest.jpa.model.Address;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "address", path = "address")
public interface AddressRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Address, Long> {
//...
}
```

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.List;

@Data
public class Bulk<T> {
    private List<T> bulk;
}
```

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.BasePathAwareController;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.ExposesResourceFor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import java.util.List;

@BasePathAwareController  // if base url exists, it needs to be added
@RepositoryRestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ExposesResourceFor(Address.class)
public class AddressController {

    private final AddressRepository repo;

    @PostMapping("/address/saveAll")
    public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Address>> saveAll(@RequestBody EntityModel<Bulk<Address>> bulk) {
        List<Address> addresses = Objects.requireNonNull(bulk.getContent()).getBulk();
        Iterable<Address> resp = repo.saveAll(addresses);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(resp,HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

The way more like Spring data rest:

```java
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.BasePathAwareController;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestController;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks;
import org.springframework.hateoas.CollectionModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.EntityModel;
import org.springframework.hateoas.Link;
import org.springframework.hateoas.server.ExposesResourceFor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@BasePathAwareController  // if base url exists, it needs to be added
@RepositoryRestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ExposesResourceFor(Address.class)
public class AddressController {

    private final AddressRepository repo;
    private final RepositoryEntityLinks entityLinks; //get link


    /**
     * curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d  '{ "bulk": [ {"country" : "Japan" , "city" : "Tokyo" }, {"country" : "Japan" , "city" : "Osaka" }]} '   http://localhost:8080/api/v1/address/saveAll
     *
     * @return 201 https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.default-status-codes
     */
    @PostMapping("/address/saveAll")
    public ResponseEntity<CollectionModel<EntityModel<Address>>>         List<Address> data = Objects.requireNonNull(bulk.getContent()).getBulk();
        Iterable<Address> addresses = repo.saveAll(data);

        ArrayList<EntityModel<Address>> models = new ArrayList<>();
        addresses.forEach(i->{
            Link link = entityLinks.linkToItemResource(Address.class, i.getId()).withRel("self");
            models.add(EntityModel.of(i).add(link));
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(CollectionModel.of(models),HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```